# Copy message rule in Outlook does not work

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I want to send all incoming emails to my private email. I opened Outlook 2010 and set up a rule for this:

- New rule on incoming messages
- no conditions
- forward to user
- no exceptions
- turn the rule on

Then I send email to this account from another address. It displays in Outlook but the copy does not reach configured account (I tried two different recepients).

I read few articles and posts in SU, this rule shall work. It shall be server side. But it does not run. Why? How can I figure out what happens?

[image: Rule setting] (sorry for czech, "použít pravidlo po příchodu nové zprávy" means "use the rule after receiving new message", "předat dále jako přílohu" means "forward as attachment")

Comment: Does Outlook show that mail is forwarded or not? Can you support your question with some SS'. Like properties of your rule.

Comment: Done, but it is in czech :-( I translated that few relevant sentences. PS I suspect that exchange administrator disabled this feature. I asked and now I wait for response.

Comment: Create a new profile and see the problem persists or not. I tried with my IMAP account, didn't work. I created a new profile then it worked.

Comment: I tried. When I started it, I could see the rule, so it was server side. I removed it and created again. I send few messages but I have not received it in target account.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this feature does not work is that system administrator has disabled the rule to send the email to an external address :-(